# CreateFile FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE fails after any handle has been closed

Tags: c++, windows, memory-mapped-files

We create a file for use as memorymappedfile.

we open with `GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE`
we use share with `FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE`
we use file attributes `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY | FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE`

we create the file successfully. We can reopen it as many times with the same flags as we want.

Once one handle has been closed, we can no longer open any more handles, it returns with ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED. We can cause this by closing any of the handles, either the first from CreateFile(ALWAYS_CREATE), or the others from CreateFile(OPEN_EXISTING).

Is there any way to avoid this ? We use the memoryMappedFile as communication between the different processes that must share resources. these processes sometimes start and stop. Right now as soon as we close one handle, we are stuck unable to open the memorymappedfile.

I have tried changing the open calls to use FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, so only the create call uses CLOSE_ON_DELETE but that has no effect on this situation.

Comment: your processes should coordinate and only the "master" should use the delete_on_close flag, the master being the first to start up and the last to shut down.

Comment: You are focusing on the wrong problem.  Yes, it is very difficult to deal with a process dying unexpectedly in this kind of scenario.  Many more things go wrong beyond a file that doesn't get deleted, a deadlock is traditional.  You often need a guard process that doesn't do anything else but ensure that everybody co-operates and cleans up when they don't.  That file that doesn't get deleted is the least of the problem, you'll get it the next time.

Answer (score 10):

The problem you're running into is that once a file handle opened with `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE` is closed, the operating system will no longer allow new handles to be created.

The gory details: When processing an `IRP_MJ_CLEANUP` (which is what happens win a handle is closed) for a file opened for delete-on-close, Windows file systems will set an internal flag on the file object indicating that it's on it's way out.  Subsequent open attempts on the file will be failed  with `STATUS_DELETE_PENDING`, which the Win32 subsystem will map to the Win32 `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` code you're seeing.

For your use case, you might want to consider using the [Named Shared Memory (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366551(v=vs.85).aspx) pattern.  Basically, let the operating system manage the space for your shared memory.  Just make sure you apply the appropriate security attributes, and you're good to go.

Comment: Thank you for the clarity. I figured as much from what I'd observed from the usermode side. Trying the delete on close flag was a recent addition to circumvent users having to add handling to their scripts.

It was for the rare case when something crashes and doesn't get cleaned up properly. 

I will look into using the pagefile as an alternative backing store for the memory mapped sections.

Gory details much appreciated and understood.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the venerable Raymond Chen [replied](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160108-00/?p=92821) to this on his Microsoft devblog, The Old New Thing. Bukes is correct but as an alternative, as Raymond says in his article:

> It looks like they really want the file to remain valid (including allowing further Create­File calls to succeed) for as long as any open handle continues to refer to the file. Fortunately, the customer needed the handle only to create a memory-mapped view. The file pointer was not important. Therefore, the customer could use Duplicate­Handle instead of Create­File to get additional handles to the file. Since all of the handles refer to the same file object, the file object will not delete the file until all of the handles are closed.